# Sync contacts with ubuntuone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, sync, linux

It doesn't look like UbuntuOne has a sync app for contacts. Files and music, yes, but not contacts. Are there any workarounds to this?

I've successfully avoided linking my phone to a google account thus far and I'd like to keep my contacts off of Google.

I'd like a good way to sync my Ubuntu One contacts to my phone without going through google.

Comment: not related to Android, unless I'm missing something

Comment: @LieRyan right ... I want to sync Ubuntu One *to my phone*

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to sync UbuntuOne  <--> Google Contacts? If you can get it to push (or sync) to Google Contacts, then it'll get pulled into your phone.

Comment: Ahh, right. I forgot to mention that I'm google free and trying to stay that way. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: As of June 1, 2011 the current Ubuntu One contacts sync for mobile will no longer be active. We’re stopping support for our current service so we can focus our energy on launching a much better service sooner than we could otherwise.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/PhoneSync/

Probably not the answer you were looking for. I am Ubuntu (3 PC, only one dual-boot) and Android ( 2 Android phones) user myself. 
I will recommend migrating to google contacts. I suppose all of your contacts are stored in "Phone" (if you are not syncing them) Most phones can easily export your contacts to a SDcard and then re-import them. When asked, select your google account, not "Phone". You should select only google contacts to be visible, to avoid duplicates.

If you want to sync your desktop mail app with online service, and you use Thunderbird (or you are OK with it), installing zindus will provide sync between thunderbird and gmail contacts. G contacts and android contacts are auto-sync with the correct options anyway.
To sum it up:
If you want a simple online solution, select google contacts (gmail)
If you want an offline  desktop app mail client, add Thunderbird +zindus to the equation

Comment: Edited my question: I'd like to do this without involving google. I'm just trying to figure out whether there are any sync workarounds to get Ubuntu One straight to my phone. Seems like there arent.

Comment: So it seems :( <br />
Bit curious, why you would like to avoid google? Scared of Big Brother? I think and hope google are playing fair enough up till now, and Canonical is just another company. :)

Comment: No so much scared as just I value my privacy. I don't love Canonical as a solution but at least all they know is what's in my address book. I'd rather store bits of data here and there than turn it over to a monolith.